# Magento 2.2.2 Store and Admin not loading

Tags: magento2.2.2, windows, xampp

```
OS Windows Server 2008
Magento 2.2.2
XAMPP 3.2.2
PHP 7.1.13
```

I was working on a local install of Magento 2.2.2 (I installed it when it was 2.2 and then when the 2.2.2 version came it auto-updated somehow) and suddenly I can't load *store* and *admin* pages. -- But not because of the update, the problem occurred after that.

The *store* returns this error in the chrome console:

```
GET http://192.168.1.100:8080/magento2/%7B%7BMEDIA_URL%7D%7Dstyles.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

The admin doesn't return nothing.

`var/log/system`:

When trying to access the *store* the logs return this:

```
[2018-03-27 08:34:44] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logger' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-03-27 08:34:48] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logger' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

When trying to access the *admin* the logs return this:

```
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Item Magento_Backend::system_currency was removed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_design_schedule was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_store was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::dashboard was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_tools was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_design was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_convert was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_cache was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing_communications was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing_seo was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing_user_content was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::content was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::content_elements was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::stores was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::stores_settings was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::stores_attributes was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::other_settings was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_other_settings was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::setup_wizard was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Config::system_config was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Theme::design_config was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Theme::system_design_theme was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_manage was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_online was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_group was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backup::system_tools_backup was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_AdminNotification::system_adminnotification was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Indexer::system_index was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Search::search_terms was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Search::search_synonyms was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Cms::cms_page was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Cms::cms_block was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_products was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_categories was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_attributes_attributes was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_attributes_sets was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::inventory was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Widget::cms_widget_instance was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Downloadable::report_products_downloads was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl_users was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl_roles was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl_locks was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_operation was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_order was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_invoice was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_shipment was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_transactions was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::system_order_statuses was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_UrlRewrite::urlrewrite was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_template was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_queue was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_subscriber was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_problem was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency_rates was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency_symbols was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Integration::system_extensions was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Integration::system_integrations was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax_rules was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax_rates was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_import was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_export was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_history was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CatalogRule::promo was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CatalogRule::promo_catalog was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Email::template was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_EncryptionKey::system_crypt_key was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Analytics::business_intelligence was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Analytics::advanced_reporting was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Analytics::bi_essentials was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Marketplace::partners was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_marketing was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_sales was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_tax was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_invoiced was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_shipping was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_refunded was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_coupons was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_shopcart_product was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_shopcart_abandoned was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_bestsellers was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_sold was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_viewed was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_lowstock was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_accounts was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_totals was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_orders was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_statistics was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_statistics_refresh was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Search::report_search_term was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_SalesRule::promo_quote was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Paypal::report_salesroot_paypal_settlement_reports was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Paypal::paypal_billing_agreement was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_ratings was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_reviews_all was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_customer was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_product was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CheckoutAgreements::sales_checkoutagreement was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sitemap::catalog_sitemap was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_TaxImportExport::system_convert_tax was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Variable::system_variable was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Braintree::settlement_report was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Blog::blog was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Blog::post was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Blog::tag was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Blog::topic was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Blog::category was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Blog::author was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Blog::configuration was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Core::menu was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Core::documentation was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Core::userguide was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Mageplaza_Core::partners was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Shopial_Facebook::marketing_social was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Shopial_Facebook::shopial_facebook was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::shipping was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::carriers was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::locations was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::packaging was processed [] []
[2018-03-27 09:10:16] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::dispatches was processed [] []
```

This log is returned 8-9 times and then then page `404`'s due to multiple redirects.

It all started when I was working on a custom page, and I had to `setup:upgrade` and then `setup:di:compile`.

The second command halts by giving an error about a module (mageplaza-blog):

```
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 1 min 2
30.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
        Mageplaza\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB
\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Mageplaza\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post
\Grid\connection; File:
C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-blog-extension/Model/Resourc
eModel/Post/Grid/Collection.php

        Mageplaza\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Tag\Grid\Collection
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB
\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Mageplaza\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Tag\
Grid\connection; File:
C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-blog-extension/Model/Resourc
eModel/Tag/Grid/Collection.php

        Mageplaza\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Topic\Grid\Collection
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB
\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Mageplaza\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Topi
c\Grid\connection; File:
C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-blog-extension/Model/Resourc
eModel/Topic/Grid/Collection.php

Total Errors Count: 3


[Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]
Error during compilation


setup:di:compile
```

At this point I couldn't load magento , but by deploying the static content I could.

Now, after failing attempts at fixing the error of `setup:di:compile` I can't load any of the pages (store, admin) not even by deploying the static content again.

What else I've tried:

`cache:clean`
`cache:flush`
`indexer:reindex`
Disabled the module `mageplaza:blog`

What can be the problem here? How could I approach this? Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time, reading this big post.

PS:

[I also made this post yesterday which  is part of the same problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219863/magento-2-2-2-error-with-read-only-folder-while-setupupgrade-and-with-a-module)

Comment: Now that you’ve disabled the extension. Remove the extension files. Then try again by deploying content and compiling code

Comment: I added the extension using the manager. Shouldn't I be able to remove it from there? The only file I could find is inside vendor, and the consensus here is that we don't touch anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I succeeded at bringing back everything by doing the following:

1. `setup:upgrade`
2. `indexer:reindex`
3. `cache:clean`
4. `cache:flush`
5. `setup:static-content:deploy`

*Note:* my `mode` is set to `developer` and the `cache` is `disabled`.

Now I should probably purge the blog module and then continue with my work, but I am a bit worried that I will crash the site again...